# How to write form validation that checks if an entered value is equal to an already saved value in the same model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to build a way for a user to type in a "code" and if the code equals the same string as a value stored in a separate model field, then allow the form to save AND update a model boolean field called "registered".

Here is my model:

```
def random_key(size=25, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))    

class Keyreg(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    privKey = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=random_key, editable = False)
    pubKey = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='feedme123')
    registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my modelForm:

```
class KeyregForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = models.Keyreg
    fields = ('pubKey',)

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(KeyregForm, self).clean()
    privKey = # data already saved in db... ?
    pubKey = cleaned_data.get('pubKey')

    if pubKey != privKey:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Your Registration Is Invalid.")
    return cleaned_data
```

Here is my View:

```
@login_required
def update_pubkey(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    pubkey = get_object_or_404(Keyreg, user=request.user)
    pub_key = Keyreg.objects.filter()


    form = KeyregForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect("/me/keyzone/")        
    return render(request, 'keyzone.html', {'form':form, 'pubkey':pubkey, 
'pub_key', pub_key})
```

1. I am looking for pubKey (user input) to equal privKey.
2. If pubKey == privKey, save the form AND change registered to TRUE.

Any help would be awesome and thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not getting your question. What exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model's instance is already in database then only you can get privKey. For this you need to pass instance of Keyreg to the form:
In your view edit this line:

```
form = KeyregForm(request.POST, instance=pubkey)
```

and modify clean method:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(KeyregForm, self).clean()
    if self.instance.pk:
        privKey = self.instance.privKey
        pubKey = cleaned_data.get('pubKey')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Diksha! This was exactly what was needed!